# Fedora can't ping 8.8.8.8 but can ping google.com

Tags: linux, networking, router, dns, fedora

[Screenshot of the pings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxlrv.jpg)

I am making my own Linux router through Fedora 27. I am using systemd-networkd configuration with my internet input file as;

```
[Match]
Name=eno1

[Network]
Address=10.125.16.32/24
Gateway=10.125.16.32
DNS=8.8.8.8
DNS=8.8.4.4
IPForward=ipv4
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv4
```

This is a physical setup which should represent my assignment [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adTdP.jpg).

I can access google, youtube and a few random sites aswell.
Does anyone have a fix for this problem?

Comment: It's not uncommon for a DNS server to reject a ping.

Comment: yes, but I cant access most sites, only google associated sites?

Comment: Actually "only IPv6-capable sites".

Comment: Thats weird considering I've only enabled ipv4.. Could you give me some pointers?

Comment: Why is the ping of google.com returning a hostname from `le100.net`? Is your ISP doing something to your traffic?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator `1e100.net` is a Google owned domain. Googol is the name of the large number 10 to the power of 100, written as `1e100` in many programming language. Google is a misspelling of Googol.

Answer (score 2):

You have set yourself as the default gateway.  That's not going to work since if your computer does not know where to send a packet and sends it to the default gateway, your computer still does not know where it send it.  You need to use the correct default gateway.